# How to detect where a variable is changed in Python?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, pydev

I would like to find out *where* a specified variable is changed with debugger tools, but fail to do that after several hours exploring both **Eclipse + PyDev** and **PyCharm**.

```
var = foo()
print(var)

bar(var)  # var is changed after calling bar(var), where is it changed? 
print(var) # var is changed
```

There is no `Toggle Watchpoint` in PyDev. Use `Breakpoint properties`? What is the condition I should type in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using @property setters . Then put a detect in the setter to see when the value changes. Search online to find out more or a good book is: Effective Python"
  Good luck.